# "When" and "Where" when we talk about hypothetical situations

Tags: grammar, adverbs, adverbials

> - **When** you need something between a comma and period, use a semicolon.
> - **Where** you need something between a comma and period, use a semicolon.

From a logical point of view, both sentences are correct, but the second one doesn't look idiomatic to me. (I could be wrong.)

On the other hand, *Where possible* looks better than *When possible*.

> - **When possible**, use a period, not a semicolon.
> - **Where possible**, use a period, not a semicolon.

- Are these observations correct?
- Generally, which word (*When* or *Where*) would be "better" to use in such cases? (Of course, it may be that there is no simple rule here.)

P.S. I don't consider *If* as a third option because it will change the meaning.

Edit: It seems plainlanguage.gov prefers *when* over *where*:

> Use the word **if** for conditions. Use **when** (not **where**), if you need **if** to introduce another clause or if the condition occurs regularly. - https://plainlanguage.gov/guidelines/organize/place-the-main-idea-before-exceptions-and-conditions/

Comment: Related, but are not duplicates: 1. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313189/is-it-common-to-use-where-after-a-time-as-a-relative, 2. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/333212/where-vs-when-a-matter-of-place-or-one-of-time

Comment: ie [Is it common to use “where” after “a time” as a relative?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313189/is-it-common-to-use-where-after-a-time-as-a-relative) and [Where vs when – a matter of place or one of… time {duplicate}](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/333212/where-vs-when-a-matter-of-place-or-one-of-time).

Comment: I'd generally use 'when' (at those times; whenever) in the first example [pair], unless I'd been looking at particular examples, and then I'd switch to 'where' (those places, those sentences). // As I think the second example pair has the analysis of particular sentences (even if no particulat sentences!) in mind, I think 'where' is the more idiomatic choice. The only time I can see myself opting for 'when' is after some unlikely prior context along the lines of 'On some old typewriters, the period key has worn smooth.' But I agree, 'where possible' is a highly idiomatic phrase.

Comment: And this one: [“In cases when” vs. “in cases where”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21413/in-cases-when-vs-in-cases-where)

Answer (score 1):

I feel this to be a simple issue. “When” relates to time and “where” to place. The two are often interchangeable but if you need a rule, stick to the simplest.

Use “when” if you are talking about when (in time) circumstances or occasion demand attention to the punctuation.

Use “where” if you are talking about places in writing where attention is needed.